# Can I use dotnet core to create a uwp app? Eg and use httpclientfactory which is only available in core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp

I’m building a uwp app that will make a rest call to a service to get some data. I would like to use HttpClientFactory provided by dotnet core. Is it possible to do this within the same project as uwp one?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. Starting with .NET Core 3 (currently in preview, due to release in September 2019) you can use .NET Core with UWP apps, [MS Devblog about it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/). But be aware that this doesn't mean that you'll be able to run UWP apps on Linux, that will probably never be possible

Answer (score 1):

> I’m building a uwp app that will make a rest call to a service to get some data.

As MindSwipe said, currently we could not use `HttpClientFactory` in UWP, if you want access service with restful api, please use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient).

For example:

```
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

//Add a user-agent header to the GET request. 
var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;

//The safe way to add a header value is to use the TryParseAdd method and verify the return value is true,
//especially if the header value is coming from user input.
string header = "ie";
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}

header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}

Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");

//Send the GET request asynchronously and retrieve the response as a string.
Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
string httpResponseBody = "";

try
{
    //Send the GET request
    httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
}
```